# In C# bool? x = true; if (x == true) looks awkward

Tags: c#-4.0

```
bool? x = true;
if (x == true)
```

looks awkward.

But sometimes that is exactly what is needed.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for the attempts, but so far I have not found a way that would beat the original. I guess I will just need to deal with awkwardness, perhaps comment it.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your situation, you may want to use the null coalescing operator, which lets you specify the default value you'll use if the `bool?` is not set. It's not shorter than your conditional, but I think it's useful:

```
if(x ?? true) //defaults to true if x is not set
```

Or, to directly replicate your case (and due to popular demand):

```
if(x ?? false) //defaults to false if x is not set
```

Comment: To be more true to the original question, you'd probably want `if (x ?? false)` so that `null` doesn't match the condition. At which point, while the code is accurate to the original intent, it's arguably less intuitive than `x == true`

Comment: To be technically correct, it should be coalesced to `false` rather since the body would be executed only if `x` was `true`.

Comment: To produce the same result as the OP's code, it should be `x ?? false` and default to false.

Comment: Actually to produce the same result you need to coalesce to `false`... *(Sorry...)*

Answer (score 1):

`if (x)` is equivalent to `if (x == true)`. There is no need to make an extra comparison since x is a boolean value.

Edit: Missed that is was nullable. In that case, it really is the best you can get unless you want to make a simple helper function.

```
bool isTrue(bool? value) {
  return value == true;
}
```

But `if (isTrue(x))` isn't much cleaner.

Comment: Except it's a `bool?`, not a `bool`.

Comment: I missed the ? because Hamish put all the code in the title instead of formatted code in the actual question.

Comment: Since .NET 4.0 is stated in the OP's tags, you could even make this an extension method. Still no cleaner than the original `x == true` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool? x = true; 
if (x.HasValue && x.Value)
{ /* Other code here */ }
```

or use `GetValueOrDefault()`, but this is no terser...

```
bool? x = true; 
if (x.GetValueOrDefault(false))
{ /* Other code here */ }
```

Comment: Unlike the original, this will throw `InvalidOperationException` on null.

Comment: Not on my machine it doesn't.  All I get is "expression is always true" warning

Comment: see the [API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx), or try yourself.